# Is timer (thread) discarded with monitor.tryenter or it will be executed later?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, monitor

I want to be sure that the following code doesn't have reentrancy. Also would like to know if threads that didn't reenter are executed later or not (I want them to be discarded).
If first timer didn't finish, will the next one be immediately fired after it does finish or it will wait 15ms extra?

Thanks

```
public void MainFunction(IntPtr h, List<int> a)
    {
        myTimer= new System.Timers.Timer();

        myTimer.Elapsed += delegate { eventfired(h, a); };
        myTimer.Interval = 15;
        myTimer.Start();
    }
    private void eventfired(IntPtr h, List<int> a)
    {
        if (System.Threading.Monitor.TryEnter(syncThreads))
        {
            try
            {
                DoWork()

            }
            finally
            {
                System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(syncThreads);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure if this is the best method or autoreset= false and start timer later on the callback is better.

The point is: only one thread working at the time and discarding created threads provided that old one is still working.

Comment: There's just no point to it, use AutoReset = false instead.  No lock required, no need to keep the threadpool busy doing nothing useful.  And forces you to think about try/catch in the Elapsed event handler, it is *not* optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works. Use the TryEnter(ref bool) overload because it's safer in the presence of exceptions.

> If first timer didn't finish, will the next one be immediately fired

Why would that be the case. The timer does not know what you are doing. It just enqueues timer ticks to the thread pool. Your TryEnter code throws collisions away.

It might happen by coincidence that multiple timer ticks execute right after another so that your code runs multiple times in succession without delay.

Comment: You mean, this one? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289679(v=vs.110).aspx?
What do you mean by "it throws collisions"?
Also, is there a way to not queue timers but to remove/delete/return them when I have the `lock` on (`dowork()` is being executed by another one)?
If it's not possible, I guess I can add a variable before `dowork()` to make sure it has to work. Otherwise, just return it. But maybe there's a more clean way to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, right overload.; Right now "duplicate" timer ticks are just not executed. I thought this is what you intended? If you want to queue them either use `lock` normally or maintain a counter of missed ticks.

Comment: This is what I want. Duplicated timers (= new timer created is on the callback function) should be discarted. Not executed now nor later. Didn't understand you meant this from your previous answer. So, if I'm inside tryenter, new timers are simply not executed, right?
Thanks, I changed my overload tryenter method.